# E155021 Unsupported working copy format

Tags: svn, netbeans

I recently switched from NetBeans 6.7.1 to 7.3.1 (from a Windows 7 system to another Windows 8). In 6.7.1 I used the CLI client from Collabnet to access the SVN repository, in 7.3.1 it is the included SvnKit of NetBeans itself.

When I tried to commit a file, I received an error:

```
svn: E155004: Working copy 'C:\Users\user1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\project1\_admin' locked
```

I then tried to cleanup the working copy, but got another error:

```
svn: E155021: Unsupported working copy format
```

In the NetBeans FAQ I read, that the inbuilt SvnKit supports different SVN formats from 1.5 onwards, thus NetBeans should support the old CLI client's format, but didn't.
I already tried to newly checkout the _admin directory of the repository but this didn't help either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the version of CLI client?

Comment: The CLI client has version 1.6.4.

Answer (score 2):

I came accross this issue as well. 
Apparently TortoiseSVN 1.8.x uses a new working copy format where Netbeans' built-in SVN library cannot cope with (yet).
For me, the solution was to downgrade TortoiseSVN to 1.7 (latest 1.7 version on http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.7.13/Application/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how SvnKit does it, but for other clients (the command-line tools, TortoiseSVN, maybe more) the working copy upgrade is a manual process. If SVNKit doesn't provide a "upgrade working copy" command, then figure out what version you have, download the associated version of the SVN command-line-tools, and upgrade your working copy using the `svn upgrade` command.

If that doesn't work, you can probably just copy your modified files off somewhere else, delete the current working copy, and check it out again using your preferred tools.

Comment: Since the inbuilt SvnKit shall support subversion formats up to 1.7, no "upgrade working copy" should be necessary. The reported error message only pops up when I tried to update a certain subdirectory or commit a file within that directory. All other operations related to other directories work fine. I guess I will try to re-checkout that directory only.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: you will get this error when you accidentally copy over an old .svn metadata folder from an SVN 1.6 working copy in one of the project's subdirectories (if you've never used SVN prior to 1.7, there was a .svn metadata folder in every subdirectory of the codebase - since SVN 1.7 there is only one .svn directory in the root). So if you're migrating code from an old project in an 1.6 repository to a new project, take care to not copy over any .svn folders.

I ran into this error when using Eclipse/Subversive with the SvnKit 1.8 provider, but since its an SVN error I'm guessing its the same under any SVN client implementation.